# Database : if exists 'update' if not exists insert

Tags: php, mysql

How to write PHP Function

If 
   row existed in db query should be Update
else
   insert query

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use php to achieve that. You can do it with pure SQL syntax using the ON DUPLICATE KEY:

Check out [MySQL INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, MySQL performs an UPDATE of the old row. For example, if column a is declared as UNIQUE and contains the value 1, the following two statements have similar effect:

Example:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name, age) VALUES(1, "A", 19) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
name="A", age=19
```